# How to modify apsrev.bst to include a period at the end of the bibliography entry?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, punctuation

I am using `apsrev` as the bibliography style file. I want to add a period at the end of the bibliography entry, i.e., "Jones et al. (1990)**.**"

How do I modify the style file?

Comment: Do you want to add the period at the end of the bibliography entry or at the end of each citation in the text? I was thinking you want the former, but the example "Jones et al. (1990)." makes me think the latter.

Comment: isn't that going to look like end of sentence and be confusing for the reader??

Comment: I want the period at the end of the bibliography entry.